# View NotFound Exception in net core6

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-6.0

I wanna Render View To Stream.
this is my code:

```
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { RequestServices = _serviceProvider };

   var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new 
   RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

var viewEngineResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, 
viewName, false);
```

this code worked before. but after update to core6 doesn't work.
net core 6 does not create view.dll
my razor view is in Views/Shared location. and i set it as content

Answer (score 0):

**Compiler no longer produces a Views assembly**

> The Razor compiler no longer produces a separate `Views.dll` file that
> contains the CSHTML views defined in an application.
>
> Both views and application types are included in a single
> `AppName.dll` assembly. View types have the accessibility modifiers
> `internal` and `sealed`, by default, and are included under the
> AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument namespace.

**So**, If your method is doing something by `View.dll`, It is not work in .Net 6

**Refer to** this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/razor-compiler-doesnt-produce-views-assembly) to learn more.